# Codeigniter Redirect or Load view with templates

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I don't know how to phrase this question on google so i couldn't find any answers.

In my Views folder, i have templates folder with header,navbar,footer inside.

Whenever i load a view from my controller i would have to do this,

```
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/navbar');
$this->load->view('pages/pagename');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

How do i do this with redirect? I don't know why but whenever i see code snippets of successful logins or failures they always use the redirect function instead of load view like the above.

for example:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()==FALSE)
    {
        redirect('pages/login');
    }
}
```

or can i use this and will this still be acceptable?

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()==FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('template/header');
      $this->load->view('template/navbar');
      $this->load->view('pages/login');
      $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()==FALSE)
    {
        redirect('controller/login');
    }
}
```

in your controller, create a function called login

```
function login() {
  $this->load->view('template/header');
  $this->load->view('template/navbar');
  $this->load->view('pages/login');
  $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In redirect you need to use **controller/method_name**

```
redirect('controllername');
```

or

```
redirect('controllername/method');
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: So redirect can also be used to call a method within a controller?

I thought it was only for views. 

Also, can it call any method from any controller? can it also call a method within the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than construct you can use remap. to redirect if the user is logged or not

REMAP

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()){
   if(method_exists($this, $method)){
      if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()==FALSE){
         return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params); //home page
      }
      return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'login'), $params); //if not logged in
  }
  show_404();
}
```

LOGIN

```
public function login() {
  $this->load->view('template/header');
  $this->load->view('template/navbar');
  $this->load->view('pages/login');
  $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```